# How to obtain the R and T of the kinect camera?

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure how to obtain the Rotation(R) and Translation(T) matrices for the kinect camera. How can i find it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10351/how-to-obtain-the-r-and-t-of-the-kinect-camera?/) by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2011-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They are available through the CameraInfoMessage published on `/camera/depth/camera_info` or `/camera/rgb/camera_info`

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) on 2011-06-23**:
You can find the message documentation if CameraInfo here http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html.  In general, you can find a link to the message documentation from the package page.  So the CameraInfo link is found here http://www.ros.org/wiki/sensor_msgs.

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-06-23**:
Wim thanks... when i type rostopic echo/camera/depth/camera_info,i get matrices D, K, R and P... what are they for?

**Comment by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) on 2011-06-22**:
Running 'rostopic list' will show you all available topics.  I'd definitely recommend the tutorials to get more comfortable with the different ROS tools and concepts http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-06-22**:
I'm not sure what more to tell you. If you're not familiar with publishing, you probably want to go over the tutorials again.

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-06-21**:
published where? sorry i am blur

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-06-21**:
It's published when you run the openni_camera node.

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-06-21**:
i can't find the /camera/rgb/camera_info. is it under additional topics?